# How Quarz Triggers works?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

It cannot be polling, should be more line a `Timer` or else. maybe implemented by `TimeWheel`.

Anyone knows HOW it works?

Comment: It's open source, you know...

Comment: Could look at the source for Quartz's `Trigger.java`: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.6/org/quartz/Trigger.java?av=f